# align (indent) in bibtex file

Tags: regular-expressions, align, bibtex

I have a bibtex file, and would like to have indentation as follows.

```
@book{moon70:trees,
       AUTHOR = {John W. Moon}, 
        TITLE = {Counting labelled trees},
         YEAR = 1970,
       SERIES = {Canadian Mathematical Monographs},
       NUMBER = 1,
    PUBLISHER = {Canadian Mathematical Congress}
}
```

I am thinking of creating a `indent-bibtex-entry` command, 
but I am stuck in steps 4 and 5.

1. Save current position, jump to the previous ocurrence of the
   regular expression `^[ \t]*@`, then to the next `{` and then to the
   next `,`.
2. While next nonblank is not `}`
3. Capture the next field with the regular expression `[ \t\n]*\([^ \t=]+\)=`.
4. Replace by `\n \1 =` where the number of spaces must make the
   total length of this expression equal to, say, 15.
5. Capture the entry's content (see caveats below), removing
   line-breaks and spaces before and after.
6. Goto 2.
7. Restore cursor's position.

**Caveats**

The content of an entry is somewhat tex-aware. 
The entries are text between quotes `"like this"`
or between matching braces `{like this}`.
**However**, you may have braces (as long as they're balanced)
inside, and escaped quotes as well `{na\"ive {example}}`.

**Simplier, but also nice**

If that is too difficult, an alternative is to define a command
`indent-field`, assuming that the line contains a single field.
The problem is similar to the previous step 4 (but here it is step 3).

1. Save current position, jump to the beginning of the line.
2. Capture the next field with the regular expression `[ \t\n]*\([^ \t=]+\)=[ \t\n*]*`.
3. Replace by `\n \1 =` where the number of spaces must make the
   total length of this expression equal to, say, 15.
4. Restore cursor's position.

Any suggestions? I am still working on the code for the items I "know" how to do.
This is my first time with elisp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution for you. I broke up the code so you might be able to learn a little elisp at the same time...

```
(defun indent-me ()
  "Indent a bibtext entry.
This assumes the entry starts with a non-white in column 0, and
ends with a } on a line by itself.  Invoke the function anywhere
inside the entry."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    ;; go to col 0 and search upwards for the start of the entry
    (goto-char (line-beginning-position))
    (while (not (looking-at "^@book"))
      (forward-line -1))
    ;; now looking at the start of entry, eg. @book
    (forward-line 1)
    (while (not (looking-at "^}"))
      (indent-one-line)
      (forward-line 1))
    ))


(defun indent-one-line ()
  "Indent one line of the entry."
  (interactive)
  (let (tokens tag newline)
    (setq tokens (split-string (line-contents)))
    (setq tag (car tokens))
    (setq tag (string-pad-left tag 15))
    (setq newline (cdr tokens))
    (setq newline (push tag newline))
    (setq newline (mapconcat 'concat newline " "))
    (goto-char (line-beginning-position))
    (kill-line)
    (insert newline)
    ))


(defun line-contents ()
  "Return the contents of the current buffer line."
  (buffer-substring-no-properties
   (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))

(defun string-pad-left (string length)
  "Return STRING padded left to LENGTH."
  (let (result)
    (while (> length (length string))
      (setq string (concat " " string)))
    (setq result string)
    result))
```

Comment: This is perfect! I managed to build a complete solution. Small tweak: I managed to remove the space-padding loop, using `make-string` instead ([manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Strings.html))

Comment: Where exactly this code should be placed?

Comment: @Viesturs, you could have this on your `~/.emacs` file, for instance, or save it in a file and then [load](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadingLispFiles) it from your `~/.emacs`.

Comment: I copied it into my ~/.emacs.d/init.el file but when I reopen emacs I see no changes in my bibtex file. And will this code not interfere with cc, tex and other files?

Comment: @Viesturs, once this code is loaded, what you have is 1) open your bibtex file; 2) position your cursor inside of the entry you want to indent, 3) `M-x indent-me` to indent that entry.